# AutoCompleteCustomSource with user names data isn't working

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to create a TextBox with auto completion.
In the constructor of my Form, I am getting data from a database and set the TextBox `AutoCompleteCustomSource` property to the user names array.
For some reason, the autocomplete feature is not working.

I am sure that there are no problems with the `db.getUsersList()` method (screenshot at the bottom).

```
public mainPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    collection.AddRange(db.getUserList().ToArray());
    nickName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you also set `nickName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;` and `nickName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;` (or `AutoCompleteMode.Suggest`)? BTW, you can just: `nickName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(db.getUserList().ToArray())`. AutoCompleteCustomSource is already a AutoCompleteStringCollection: you don't need another one to set it, you can do this directly..

Comment: What does it mean *different types*? You have to specify the `AutoCompleteSource`. What is it?. From what you're showing here, it's a CustomSource.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally did that - `nickName.AutoCompleteSource = nickName.AutoCompleteCustomSource;` :DD

Comment: Can you send it as an answer, i will set it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup a control that supports auto completion, it's necessary to specify the source of the AutoComplete feature. When set to a string collection using the [AutoCompleteCustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource) property, the [AutoCompleteSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource) property must be set to [AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autocompletesource) and [AutoCompleteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode) set to either `AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend` or `AutoCompleteMode.Suggest`.

These properties **must be used together** to specify how the AutoComplete feature works.

Since it appears the code in the question is using some sort of data source to create the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` collection, here's a generic example that creates a `CustomSource` from a `List<class>`, adds bindings to the controls using a `Binding` class and updates the values of some controls using a `BindingSource`.

The example, as seen it visual sample, uses three control: a TextBox (**`txtAutoComp`**), where the AutoComplete feature is enabled, and two Labels (**`lblNickName`** and **`lblNickValue`**), bound to the same data source, which are updated when the text of AutoComple control changes.
The AutoComplete is expanded to allow to find elements using partial strings, either clicking a Button (**`btnFindNick`**, here) or pressing the `Enter` key in the TextBox:

[image: TextBox AutoCompleteCustomSource]

```
private class NickName
{
    public string Nick { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

private BindingSource source = null;
private List<NickName> NickNames = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NickNames = new List<NickName>();
    NickNames.AddRange(new[] {
        new NickName() { Nick = "", Value = 0 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Andrea", Value = 10 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Arnold", Value = 20 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Barbara", Value = 30 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Billy", Value = 40 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Clint", Value = 50 },
        new NickName() { Nick = "Cindy", Value = 60 },
    });
    source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = NickNames;

    txtAutoComp.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    txtAutoComp.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtAutoComp.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(NickNames.Select(n => n.Nick).ToArray());

    Binding textBind = new Binding("Text", source, "Nick", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    textBind.Parse += (s, evt) => {
        source.CurrencyManager.Position = NickNames.FindIndex(1, r => r.Nick.Equals(evt.Value));
    };

    txtAutoComp.DataBindings.Add(textBind);
    lblNickName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", source, "Nick"));
    lblNickValue.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", source, "Value"));
}

private void btnFindNick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindNick(txtAutoComp.Text);
}

private void txtAutoComp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        FindNick(txtAutoComp.Text);
    }
}

void FindNick(string partialName) 
    => this.source.CurrencyManager.Position = NickNames.FindIndex(
        1, r => r.Nick.Contains(partialName)
    );
```