# Flashing textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

For some reason, if  I am changing the textbox's `AutoCompleteCustomSource` property, it disappears for a second and then shows up. I've tried to do it in another thread, but it doesn't seem to help, any ideas?

Code without external thread:

```
private void nickName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Thread updateAC = new Thread(updateAutoComplete);
            //updateAC.Start();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection.AddRange(db.getUsersByLetters(nickName.Text).ToArray());
            nickName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            ((mainForm)Parent).currentNick = nickName.Text;    
            error.Visible = false;
        }
```

Code with external thread:

```
        private void nickName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread updateAC = new Thread(updateAutoComplete);
            updateAC.Start();
            ((mainForm)Parent).currentNick = nickName.Text;    
            error.Visible = false;
        }

        public delegate void InvokeDelegate();
        private void updateAutoComplete()
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection.AddRange(db.getUsersByLetters(nickName.Text).ToArray());
            nickName.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => { nickName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;}));
        }
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: See the example I posted in your previous question: [AutoCompleteCustomSource with user names data isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55558178/7444103). You don't have to recreate the list with each char you insert, you create the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` once, update it only if the DataSource changes. You **definitely** don't have to use a thread for this.

Comment: In this situation i cannot just AddRange, because then i'll add some data to autocompletesource every time user changing the text. I don't want that, so i am recreating it every time.

Comment: That's not how the autocomplete feature works. See that example again. Note that the AutoComplete TextBox also has a Binding (which I don't see here). See how that is resolved, without loading anything more than once. I posted that example for this reason.

Comment: that binding is in the constructor of Form. Autocomplete is working. The question is, why the textbox is flashing? If I get all the names from db one time everything will be fine, but if I am making a request when text is changed it flashes for some reason.

Comment: The TextBox is flashing because you're rebuilding it's AutoCompleteSource with each keystroke. You don't have to do that. Ever.

Comment: But if I had like 1 million names in DB, the request will take too long, so I can't just get all names at once... So I am updating names with each keystroke.

Comment: If you had that kind of data source, the search would be implemented using a database lookup, not with a `string[]` as source. The AutoCompleteCustomSource can hold a lot of data without glitching out, anyway. Test it as I described.

Comment: If I don't update it repeatedly it works fine, but I think request that selects all data from a database at once is a bad request...

Comment: That's a generic statement. It's fine in this case. If you will actually have millions of users, you'll need a complete redefinition of everything you have now.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, thanks for your attention, I understand that I am some kind of annoying, but I just want to understand what I should do and why c:

Comment: Why annoying? You're just asking some questions. Anyway, you could just try the AutoComplete feature of your textbox filling it with a million of random strings and see how it works.